# drawing quadratic function graphs using canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, pascal

Hi everyone I’m doing an exercise where i have to solve quadratic equation (a*x^2+ b*x+ c) where x1 and x2 are the solutions then i have to draw the graph of the function but before i have to find  Xmin  Xmax  where
if(x1  > x2) then   Xmin := (2 * x2) - x1 and  Xmax := (2 * x1) - x2
if(x2 > x1)  then   Xmin := (2 * x1) - x2  and Xmax := (2 * x2) - x1;
then I have find all possible value for y and store all the values of  x  and  y  in twodimensional array and display it in Listbox.
Then using the value of this  array I have to draw function graph in TPaintbox using canavas
My code so far look like this  but I’m stuck  because I don’t know how to fit numbers from the array  as coordinates

```html
var
  Form1    : TForm1;
  a ,b ,c ,x1, x2, xi, yi, XmaxC, Xmin, Xmax  : real;    
 
 implementation

{$R *.lfm}  

  function delta(a, b, c : real): real;
begin
  delta := (b * b) - (4 * a  * c);
end;

procedure TForm1.ObliczClick(Sender: TObject);
    type
       tWspolrzedne =(x,y);
    var
       TabWart : array[tWspolrzedne,1..1000] of real;
       j, i, k, XminC, XmaxC     : integer;


begin
  ListBox.Items.Clear;
  


  a := strtofloat(licz1.text);
  b := strtofloat(licz2.text);
  c := strtofloat(licz3.text);

  if(delta(a, b, c) = 0) then
    begin
       x1 := -b / (2 * a);
       x2 := -b / (2 * a);

       Memo.Lines.Add(floattostr(x1));
    end
  else
     if(delta(a, b, c) > 0) then
       begin
          x1 := (-b - sqrt(delta(a, b, c))) / (2 *a);
          x2 := (-b + sqrt(delta(a, b, c))) / (2 *a);
          Memo.Lines.Add(floattostr(x1)+'  ,  '+ floattostr(x2));
       end
  else
      begin
        ShowMessage('negative delta ');
      end;

                                      //  Xmin i Xmax
 if(x1 >x2) then
   begin
      Xmin := (2 * x2) - x1;
      Xmax := (2 * x1) - x2;
      edit1.text := floatTostr(Xmin);
      edit2.text := floatTostr(Xmax);
   end
 else
     if(x2 > x1)then
       begin
         Xmin := (2 * x1) - x2;
         Xmax := (2 * x2) - x1;
         edit1.text  := floatTostr(Xmin);
         edit2.text:= floatTostr(Xmax);

       end;

  xi := Xmin;
  for i := 1 to 850 do
     begin
     yi := a * (xi) * (xi) + b * (xi) + c;
     TabWart[x,i]:= xi;
     TabWart[y,i]:= yi;
     listBox.Items.Add(inttostr(i) +floatTostr(xi)+'  ,  '+ floattostr(yi));
     xi := xi + 0.1;

   end;// her I m just experimenting 

   XminC := trunc(Xmin);
   XmaxC := trunc(Xmax);
    ShowMessage(inttostr(XmaxC));
   if (XminC < 0) and (XmaxC > 0)then
     begin

        XmaxC := XmaxC +350;
        XminC := 350 + Xminc;


     end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know max and min for x and y values, and define rectangle for drawing.

You can find value limits in your for-loop like this:

```
yi := a * (xi) * (xi) + b * (xi) + c; 
ymin := Min(ymin, yi) ;
ymax := Max(ymax, yi) ;
```

or use `Math.MaxValue` over whole array after loop

```
ymin := Math.MinValue(TabWart[y]) ;
ymax := Math.MaxValue(TabWart[y]) ;
```

To draw a single static plot, `TPaintBox` in not so good, because it needs redrawing (it is good for dynamic drawings), so try use `TImage`. If you need to place plot in image region limited by `XLeft, XRight, YTop, YBottom`, you need to transform  values to integer coordinates with such formulas:

```
xx := XLeft + Round ((TabWart[x, i] - xmin) * (XRight - XLeft) / (xmax - xmin));
yy := YBottom - Round ((TabWart[y, i] - ymin) * (YRight - YLeft) / (ymax - ymin));
```

Also consider using of `TChart` if available

Comment: thanks for your answer  in the  exercise it is obligatory to use tPaintbox and canvas

Comment: @jak_es Your TabWart array is perfect for dynamic painting. You have to paint it from TPaintBox OnPaint event using Canvas.MoveTo and Canvas.LineTo.

Comment: @jak_es TabWart must be a field in the form, not a local variable so that it keeps his values and be accessible from OnPaint handler.